# Getting char* and size_t from C to ruby, and pass them from Ruby to C without FFI (using SWIG)

Tags: c, ruby, swig

I have question because I'm out of ideas here. I have c library wrapped with SWIG. I do not use FFI because I don't want to have any 3rd party dependencies in my GEM. The thing is I faced some problem. I have function in C that is creating char* buffer and returns it size. I need to return to ruby size of the buffer and buffer itself. With size_t isn't big problem, I can store it on ruby side as int, and cast it later after going back to C, but I have problem with char*.

When I return char* from C to ruby it's converted to string. So I cannot return it to C as char* anymore. I was trying to do some dirty things like taking memory address of char*, store it as string and pass it back to C but doesn't work neither.

what is use case. I need to link two ruby threads using 3rd party c library. So I need to create link instance on thread one and pass char* and size_t pointers to thread2, an there initialize link. So there is no option of changing this approach.

The question is, is it possible to pass reference to char* pointer C -> Ruby -> C and how to do that. I'm digging for solutions since 2 days but I have no good ideas here.

Thx in advance :)

Example function that returns char* from C to Ruby

```
char* link_rb() {
    size_t in_process_link_size = 0;
    link_create(NULL, 0, &in_process_link_size);
    unsigned char* in_process_link = NULL;
        if (in_process_link_size != 0) {
            in_process_link = (unsigned char*)malloc(in_process_link_size);
            if (in_process_link != NULL)
                in_process_link_size = link_create(in_process_link, in_process_link_size, NULL);
        }
    
    return in_process_link;
}
```

link_create is not my function I need to use it here (cannot change it).

And on the other side I need do something like this:

```
tracer_handle_t tracer_create_rb(unsigned char const* link) {
    size_t link_size = 40;

    char* buffer = (char*) &link;
    
    size_t tracer = inprocesslinktracer_create(link, link_size);
    return tracer;
}
```

inprocesslinktracer_create is as well not my function. Came from SDK

Let's assume for now that I will return only char* and pass it as well as single parametr. In general I need as well size of the buffer, I can go to struct here but first I want to figure it out here.

Comment: SWIG has a lot of capabilities for customizing mappings, but it would help with the specifics if you presented the signatures of the functions you are trying to wrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The question is, is it possible to pass reference to char* pointer C -> Ruby -> C

Yes.

SWIG does by default assume that objects of type `char *` should be wrapped so as to give access to the pointed-to data, not the pointer itself.  This is different from how it handles other pointers.  However, SWIG's mapping behavior is customizable via [Typemaps](https://www.swig.org/Doc4.1/SWIGDocumentation.html#Typemaps), and where necessary, you can help it out by writing a shim (not needed for the example presented).

The example code could be served with simple input and output typemaps:

**mymodule.i**

```
%module mymodule

/* Relying on SWIG to #include <ruby.h> */
%typemap(in) unsigned char const *AS_NUMBER {
    $1 = (unsigned char const *) NUM2ULL($input);
}
%typemap(out) char *link_rb {
    $result = ULL2NUM((unsigned long long) $1);
}

%{
#include "tracer.h"
%}

/*
 * We don't want SWIG to process all of tracer.h.  This is what we actually
 * want wrapped, and any additional declarations needed to fully define that.
 * These declarations need to be compatible with the those in tracer.h:
 */
#include <stddef.h>
typedef size_t tracer_handle_t;

char *link_rb(void);
tracer_handle_t tracer_create_rb(unsigned char const *AS_NUMBER);
```

The `in` typemap specifies a Ruby -> C conversion for parameters or objects matching the given name and datatype.  Similarly, the `out` typemap specifies a C -> Ruby conversion for return values or objects matching the given name and datatype.  Note that the `AS_NUMBER` has only the significance given it by that interface file.  It is not special to SWIG.

> In general I need as well size of the buffer, I can go to struct here but first I want to figure it out here.

As you like.

Comment: Just to clarify, if I will change char* to mystruct*, algorithm should be the same?

Comment: @skrystos, you ought to be able to substitute `mystruct *` for `char *` in the code presented in this answer, yes.  If you just want to ferry a structure pointer from one C function to another then that should do the job just fine, but if you want to access the pointed-to structure from Ruby then that's another story.

Comment: I just want to pass pointer. Thank you